# CHECKDB Allocation Errors Msg 2576, could not repair, object id does not exist

Tags: sql-server, corruption, dbcc-checkdb

I inherited a database that has no value in LastKnownGood. I ran repair allow data loss, says it was successfully repaired, but no change to the errors when I run checkdb again. In case it was a SQL 2000 database previously I ran updateusage, still no help. I tried my best to go through [Paul Randal's IAM corruption blogs](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/iam-page-corruption-examples/), but I'm too nervous without guidance because the reference object_id doesn't exist. Any help is appreciated, unfortunately this corruption exists in all backups.

```
DBCC CHECKALLOC (mydb)
```

Output:

```
Msg 2576, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The Index Allocation Map (IAM) page (0:0) is pointed to by the previous pointer of IAM page (1:155005) in object ID 1489440380, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594086817792, alloc unit ID 72057594109886464 (type In-row data), but it was not detected in the scan.
Msg 2576, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The Index Allocation Map (IAM) page (0:0) is pointed to by the previous pointer of IAM page (1:146209) in object ID 1489440380, index ID 2, partition ID 72057594086883328, alloc unit ID 72057594109952000 (type In-row data), but it was not detected in the scan.
Msg 2576, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The Index Allocation Map (IAM) page (0:0) is pointed to by the previous pointer of IAM page (1:158251) in object ID 1489440380, index ID 3, partition ID 72057594086948864, alloc unit ID 72057594110017536 (type In-row data), but it was not detected in the scan.
Msg 2576, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The Index Allocation Map (IAM) page (0:0) is pointed to by the previous pointer of IAM page (1:169275) in object ID 1489440380, index ID 4, partition ID 72057594087014400, alloc unit ID 72057594110083072 (type In-row data), but it was not detected in the scan.
```

Comment: If all backups possess corruption, and the object_id doesn't actually exist, my next approach would probably be to create a brand new database, copy all of the existing objects to it, then drop the old database and rename the new one. This is potentially a lot of work, but may be the fastest and simplest fix.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will recreate the database and move all objects.